# Constraints for wCompact hRegular

Tags: ios, iphone

The app has to be rendered in Portrait mode of all iPhones. So i had given `wCompact|hRegular`. Currently i'm using XCode 6.1.1

My question is when using `wCompact|hRegular`, how to provide constraints separately according to **iPhone 3.5** inch, **iPhone 4** inch, **iPhone 4.7** inch & **iPhone 5.5** inch.

Answer (score 0):

There is so many steps to do that. you can refer this link which will clear your ideas against multi screen constraints.

http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

Comment: I had already gone through the site but I cannot able to get the answer for the question i had asked here. Also in one of the site, it was noted that apple had provided generic specification regarding the **wCompact|hRegular** but failed to give specific according to inch. Kindly let me know how to give constraints according to the iPhone inches specifically in **wCompact|hRegular**.